# using Ext.Ajax.request ,showing session timeout

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs

I am using Ext.Ajax.request to communicate to springMVC to get the response(I am getting the response)
as soon as i login,and after successful login,i am showing home.jsp but here,extjs status message pops up(which i have not written),displaying "session expired".Is this is ExtJS issue or browser,
here is my login.js

```
Ext.onReady(login);

function login()
{
var LoginPanel = new Ext.FormPanel(
{
    id:'pnlLogin',
    border:0,
    height:125,
    bodyPadding: 20,
    width:300,
    defaultType : 'textfield',      
    fieldDefaults: {
                labelWidth: 75
    },
    items:[
    {
        fieldLabel: 'User ID',
        allowBlank: false,  
        id: 'loginUserName'         
    },
    {
        fieldLabel: 'Password',
        id: 'loginPswd',
        allowBlank: false,
        inputType : 'password'
    }   ],
    buttons:[
    {
        text:'Login',
        formBind: true,
        handler: function()
        {
            var form = LoginPanel.getForm();
            var userName = LoginPanel.getForm().findField('loginUserName').getValue();
            var pswd = LoginPanel.getForm().findField('loginPswd').getValue();


                    Ext.Ajax.request({

                    url: 'login.htm',
                    method: 'POST',
                    timeout: 120000,
                    params : 
                    {
                        userName: userName,
                        password: pswd
                    },


                    success: function (response) {   


                      var jsonResp = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);

                            Ext.Msg.alert("Info","UserName from Server : "+jsonResp.msg);
                             window.location = 'home.jsp';
                           },
                      failure: function (response) {
                          var jsonResp = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                          Ext.Msg.alert("Error",jsonResp.error);
                           }

                    });

        }
    }
    ]
});


var loginWin = new Ext.Window(
{
    id : 'loginWin',
    title:'Login',
    layout : 'hbox',
    width : 400,
    height : 200,
    bodyStyle:'background-color:#fff;padding: 10px',  
    closable : false,
    resizable : false,
    plain : true,
    border : 2,             
    draggable : false,
    items : [LoginPanel]            
});
loginWin.show();
}
```

Can anybody help!!!

Answer (score 1):

If the error is on the home.jsp and you have not written an error handler - then how can it be an extjs issue? Is the alert you get a browser native alert window?

Comment: :thanks,actually i was checking for cookie in .js file which is included in home.jsp,so cookie was false so i was going in if condition,and so status messg pop up..i corrected it.Thnsk a lot....